# Using a dynamic array inside a class -- Receiving error at compile time

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

***QUESTION ANSWERED IN COMMENTS***  Because of my reputation, I can't answer it in the regular fashion. I'll add details in an answer later, already addressed in comments. Thanks.****

Hello all -

As you'll no doubt see based on the question, I'm new to C++, but have experience with some higher level languages. (Which seems to be hurting more than helping)

For a class, I need to create a wrapper for an Array that is typed to integers. (No templates at this stage of class) I also need to allow the class to have a non-zero starting index. I'm using a member array in the class to store my data (no vectors yet at this point of the class) and doing some translation from the public methods to access the appropriate internal array element.

The problem that I'm running into is that I don't know the internal array size at compile time, so I'm declaring it as a class global pointer and setting up the size in the constructor. A code snippet is below in the problem area:

```
int *list;
safeArray::safeArray(int start, int initialSize)
{
    if(initialSize <= 0)
    {
        throw "Array size must be a positive integer";
    }
    maxSize = initialSize + 1;
    startIndex = start;
    endIndex = start + initialSize;
    list = new int[maxSize];    // Error thrown here
    int *tempArray = new int[maxSize];
    copyArray(tempArray);
    clearArray();   
}
```

The error I'm getting is

`Incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int[0u]'`

I'm not 100% sure what the type of int[0u] is. Is that the literal value zero and the u is for unsigned? I've checked in the debugger that maxSize holds a value and I've also replaced it with a constant integer value and got the same error.

Because my `int *tempArray = new int[maxSize];`  line worked, I thought it might have something to do with needing to declare and size at the same time, so I opted to do a memcpy. (Which is actually outside the scope of the assignment, so there must be something else I'm missing) The memcpy fails because it appears that I'm clobbering my other variables. When I print the address of list in GDB, it gives me the same address as another global variable in my code, so that route also seemed it was out of the scope of the assignment.

The common theme I've seen in other forums is that you can't assign arrays like other variables, but I didn't think that would include the `new` statement. Am I wrong in that assumption?

The only compilation errors I'm currently seeing is the one stated above, and I see it for every `list = new int[maxSize];` statement in the code.

My questions are:

1. What is the type int[0u] and where is that type being generated? It would have to be from the new statement right?
2. What is the best way to utilize a dynamic array resource inside of a class? Besides using a vector? =)

I think that's all the relevant info, but my apologies if I missed a crucial piece of data. Below is the rest of the implementation code.

```
/*
 *  safeArray.cpp
 *  safearray
 *
 *  Created by Jeffery Smith on 6/1/11.
 *  
 *
 */

#include "safeArray.h"
#include &lt;iostream&gt;


using namespace std;


    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = 0;
    int maxSize = 1;
    int currentSize = 0;
    int *list;

safeArray::safeArray(int start, int initialSize)
{
    if(initialSize <= 0)
    {
        throw "Array size must be a positive integer";
    }
    maxSize = initialSize + 1;
    startIndex = start;
    endIndex = start + initialSize;
    list = new int[maxSize];    // Error thrown here
    int *tempArray = new int[initialSize + 1];
    copyArray(tempArray);
    clearArray();

}

safeArray::safeArray(const safeArray &sArray)
{
    list = new int[sArray.maxSize];
    copyArray(sArray);
    startIndex = sArray.startIndex;
    endIndex = sArray.endIndex;
    maxSize = sArray.maxSize;
    currentSize = sArray.currentSize;
}

void safeArray::operator=(const safeArray &right)
{
    list = new int[right.maxSize];
    copyArray(right);
    startIndex = right.startIndex;
    endIndex = right.endIndex;
    maxSize = right.maxSize;
    currentSize = right.currentSize;
}

safeArray::~safeArray()
{
    delete [] list;
}



int safeArray::operator[](int index)
{
    if(OutofBounds(index))
    {
        throw "You tried to access an element that is out of bounds";
    }
    return list[index - startIndex];
}

void safeArray::add(int value)
{
    if(this->isFull())
    {
        throw "Could not add element. The Array is full";
    }
    currentSize++;
    list[currentSize + startIndex];
}

void safeArray::removeAt(int value)
{
    if(OutofBounds(value))
    {
        throw "The requested element is not valid in this list";
    }
    compressList(value);
    currentSize--;
}

void safeArray::insertAt(int location, int value)
{
    if(OutofBounds(location) || this->isFull())
    {
        throw "The requested value is either out of bounds or the list is full";
    }
    expandList(location, value);
    currentSize++;
}


void safeArray::clearList()
{
    clearArray();
}

bool safeArray::isFull()
{
    return(maxSize == currentSize);
}

int safeArray::length()
{
    return currentSize;
}

int safeArray::maxLength()
{
    return this->maxSize;
}

bool safeArray::isEmpty()
{
    return(currentSize == 0);
}

bool safeArray::OutofBounds(int value)
{
    return (value > endIndex || value < startIndex);
}

void safeArray::clearArray()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
    {
        list[i] = 0;
    }
    currentSize = 0;
}

void safeArray::compressList(int value)
{
    for(int i = value; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        list[i] = list[i + 1];
    }
}

void safeArray::expandList(int location, int value)
{
    int tempHolder = list[location];
    list[location] = value;
    for(int i = location; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        tempHolder = list[location];
        list[location] = value;
        value = tempHolder;
    }
}

void safeArray::copyArray(int *srcAddr )
{

    memcpy(list, srcAddr, sizeof(int) * maxSize);

}

void safeArray::copyArray(const safeArray &sArray)
{

    memcpy(list, &sArray, sizeof(int) * maxSize);

}
```

Here is the header definition:

```
/*
 *  safeArray.h
 *  safearray
 *
 *  Created by Jeffery Smith on 6/1/11.
 *  Copyright 2011 Accenture. All rights reserved.
 *
 */



class safeArray {

public:
    safeArray(int,int);    //Standard constructor
    ~safeArray();          //Destructor
    int operator[](int);
    void operator=(const safeArray&);   //Assignment overload
    safeArray(const safeArray &sArray); //Copy Constructor

    void add(int);
    int maxLength();
    int length();
    bool isFull();
    bool isEmpty();
    void clearList();
    void removeAt(int);
    void insertAt(int,int);

protected:
    int list[];
    int startIndex;
    int endIndex;
    int maxSize;
    int currentSize;

private:
    void clearArray();
    bool OutofBounds(int);
    void expandList(int,int);
    void compressList(int);
    void copyArray(int*);
    void copyArray(const safeArray&);
};
```

Comment: Please post the definition of `class safeArray`. Does it have a member named `list`? Do you have any `list` declared as an array, not a pointer. Also note that using `using namespace std;` when you have names like `list` that duplicate things in the `std` namespace is likely to cause you problems.

Comment: You should throw `std::exception` (or subclass) instances, instead of `const char*`. Also, don't use `<pre>` or `<code>` here, indent the code with 4 spaces.

Comment: If ever a class had a misleading name, it is this one :-)

Comment: yes, namespace std contains class named list. Remove that line and try again, or rename your variable. Also, you declaring variable list as local variable, not as class member, that will cause errors if you create two or more instances of your array...

Comment: 1. The compiler seems to believe that you have a `list` somewhere that might be declared `int list[]` or `int list[0]`. Do you?  2. Using a `std::vector` really **is** a good idea. Don't you start to see that now?  :-)

Comment: @Bo lol! Yes I saw it a looong time ago. I just want to see what I'm missing so that.

Comment: @Bo and you were correct. I had an old declaration of int list[] in my header file that I never updated to a pointer. So that solved my problem. I knew it had to be something simple. The course is an independent study, so I'm not working with anyone. Sometimes you just need a second set of eyes. Thanks so much! I'll file this away in "stupid things to check fist"

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus   Thanks for the feedback. The exception thing I did was really just a sort of place holder until I did more research on Exceptions. That's also not part of the assignment yet, but wanted something in there until I dug a bit more.  Also sorry about the <pre><code> thing. I"ll remember that in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @Charles -- Yeah, it turned out I had an old declaration in there causing the problem. Thanks. Also I didn't think about the generic nature of list as a variable. It didn't cause any problems, but I changed it in my code just to be safe. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bo helped me out in the comments. Turns out I had an old int list[] declaration in my header file that I never changed. So that compiler error it was throwing was due to the declaration there. After that everything was gravy.

Answer (score 0):

`int[0u]`? I believe that you can, in C, have zero-length arrays at the end of structures to permit the use of variable-sized structures, effectively, but this is not done in C++. I don't see anything in your code that would be illegal code. Terrible, yes, illegal, no. You need to post the contents of `safearray.h`, if it includes Standard headers, then your use of `using namespace std;` could easily be the cause of the problem.

Also, global variables are bad. Just put the pointer inside the class- you should basically never have to use global variables unless you're doing something very wrong. Especially as it, say, leaves you open to variable shadowing, names clashes, and other, massive, problems. Oh, and you should throw an exception class, preferably derived from `std::exception` or `std::runtime_error`. Nobody will try to catch a `const char*`. You shouldn't use the `std` namespace- you're begging for problems. And you're not invoking the copy constructor or assignment operator, but using memcpy to copy your elements? You've also leaked memory in several places- starting with the assignment operator.

```
template<typename T> class safe_array {
    char* list;
    std::size_t arrsize;
    void valid_or_throw(std::size_t index) {
        if (index <= arrsize) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Attempted to access outside the bounds of the array.");
    }
public:
    safe_array(std::size_t newsize) 
    : list(NULL) {
        size = arrsize;
        list = new char[arrsize];
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < arrsize; i++) {
            new (&list[i * sizeof(T)]) T();
        }
    }
    safe_array(const safe_array& ref) 
    : list(NULL) {
        *this = ref;
    }
    safe_array& operator=(const safe_array& ref) {
        clear();
        arrsize = ref.size;
        list = new char[arrsize];
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < arrsize; i++) {
            new (&list[i * sizeof(T)]) T(ref[i]);
        }        
    }
    T& operator[](std::size_t index) {
        valid_or_throw(index);
        return static_cast<T&>(list[index * sizeof(T)]);
    }
    const T& operator[](std::size_t index) {
        valid_or_throw(index);
        return static_cast<const T&>(list[index * sizeof(T)]);
    }
    void clear() {
        if (list == NULL)
            return;
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            (*this)[i].~T();
        }
        delete[] list;
        list = NULL;
        arrsize = 0;
    }
    std::size_t size() {
        return arrsize;
    }
    bool empty() {
        return (list == NULL);
    }
    ~safe_array() {
        clear();
    }
};
```

A relatively quick *sample* class I whipped up that should point you more in the general direction. It doesn't offer all the functionality of a `vector`, no automatic resizing for example or capacity buffering (and a few other shortcomings) and I'm quite confident I probably forgot a couple things, but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks DeadMG. Are you seeing a global variable in the code? I use a global class variable. It's not global to the program, just to the class. Is that the wrong terminology? Did I declare it wrong in my code?

Comment: Another question for you DeadMG. I see in your statement that I've leaked memory in the assignment operator overload. Should I be releasing list? It's a resource in the class that gets released in the destructor method. Is that not sufficient?